# Regex Look-behind doesn't work for splitting string at document ID

Tags: python, regex

I have this string

```
string = "line\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nDocument AAA123\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nDocument AAA124\n"
```

which I want to parse as a list:

```
result = ["line\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nDocument AAA123","\nline\nline\nline\nline\nline\nDocument AAA124"]
```

thus extracting strings **up to and including** Document ID. I tried to follow a strategy with `Look-behind`

```
l = re.split(r"(?<=\\nDocument)(\b\w\b)", string)
```

but as result I obtain list of length 1. Should I do otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of splitting, capture what you want using this pattern

```
([\s\S]+?Document.+)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/143)

or in your case `([\s\S]+?\\nDocument.+)`